# How to simulate column-count CSS 3 property with CSS 2 engine?

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

I have to make an html document to be rendered as PDF, and the engine only supports CSS 2.1.

A big part of the text should be displayed on 2 columns, which is well achieved with `column-count: 2`.

Unfortunately this property is not understood by the PDF engine, so I'd like to know if there are some tricks to do the same thing with CSS 2.1.

Without of course having to handle where the break is, since the text might change.

Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the spec of CSS2 I coudn't find anything that would solve your problem without changing the HTML structure, can you use any scripting language to process the document previously?

Comment: @Gunther unfortunately no I can't use script. I'm afraid I'll have to split the text manually  in a table (and the user will have to every time the text - part of a contract - changes). Thanks for having tried.